# Bind data frames on longer identifiers R

Tags: r, merge, frame

I've got two data frames in which the unique identifiers common to both frames differ in the number of observations. I would like to create a dataframe from both in which the observations from each frame are taken if they have more observations for a common identifier. For example:

```
f1 <- data.frame(x = c("a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "c"), y = c(1,1,2,3,3,3))
f2 <- data.frame(x = c("a","b", "b", "c", "c"), y = c(4,5,5,6,6))
```

I would like this to generate a merge based on the longer x such that it produces:

```
x y 
a 1
a 1
b 5
b 5
c 3
c 3 
c 3
```

Any and all thoughts would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using `split`

```
dd<-rbind(cbind(f1, s="f1"), cbind(f2, s="f2"))

keep<-unsplit(lapply(split(dd$s, dd$x), FUN=function(x) {
    y<-table(x)
    x == names(y[which.max(y)])
}), dd$x)

dd <- dd[keep,]
```

Normally i'd prefer to use the `ave` function here but because i'm changing data.types from a factor to a logical, it wasn't as appropriate so I basically copied the idea that `ave` uses and used `split`.

Answer (score 1):

### `dplyr` solution

```
library(dplyr)
```

#### First we combine the data:

with `rbind()` and introduce a new variable called `ref` to know where each observation came from:

```
both <- rbind( f1, f2 )
both$ref <- rep( c( "f1", "f2" ) , c( nrow(f1), nrow(f2) ) )
```

#### then count the observations:

make another new variable that contains how many observations for each `ref` and `x` combination:

```
both_with_counts <- both %>% 
                         group_by( ref ,x ) %>% 
                         mutate( counts = n() )
```

#### then filter for the largest count:

```
both_with_counts %>% group_by( x ) %>% filter( n==max(n) )
```

*note: you could also select only the `x` and `y` cols with `select(x,y)`...*

this gives:

```
## Source: local data frame [7 x 4]
## Groups: x
## 
##  x y ref counts
##  1 a 1  f1 2
##  2 a 1  f1 2
##  3 c 3  f1 3
##  4 c 3  f1 3
##  5 c 3  f1 3
##  6 b 5  f2 2
##  7 b 5  f2 2
```

## Altogether now...

```
what_I_want <- 
  rbind(cbind(f1,ref = "f1"),cbind(f2,ref = "f2")) %>%
  group_by(ref,x) %>% 
  mutate(counts = n()) %>%
  group_by( x ) %>% 
  filter( counts==max(counts) ) %>%
  select( x, y )
```

and thus:

```
> what_I_want
# Source: local data frame [7 x 2]
# Groups: x
# 
# x y
# 1 a 1
# 2 a 1
# 3 c 3
# 4 c 3
# 5 c 3
# 6 b 5
# 7 b 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a elegant answer but still give the desired result. Hope this help.

```
f1table <- data.frame(table(f1$x))
colnames(f1table) <- c("x","freq")
f1new <- merge(f1,f1table)

f2table <- data.frame(table(f2$x))
colnames(f2table) <- c("x","freq")
f2new <- merge(f2,f2table)

table <- rbind(f1table, f2table)
table <- table[with(table, order(x,-freq)), ]
table <- table[!duplicated(table$x), ]

data <-rbind(f1new, f2new)
merge(data, table, by=c("x","freq"))[,c(1,3)]
  x y
1 a 1
2 a 1
3 b 5
4 b 5
5 c 3
6 c 3
7 c 3
```